# write file to structs

Tags: c, file, data-structures, struct

I want to write and read some statics from file to structs.
write from structs to file is work of but write data from file isn't ok.
I will be grateful to help me what is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char* MemberFormatIn="(%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %d)";
const char* MemberFormatOut="(%s, %s, %s, %d)\n";

typedef struct member {
    char name[20],
        lastName[20],
        address[20];
    int age;
}p1,p2;

void inputMemberList(struct member p[],int count) {
    
    printf("name:");
    scanf("%s",p[count].name);

    printf("lastName:");
    scanf("%s",p[count].lastName);

    printf("address:");
    scanf("%s",p[count].address);

    printf("age:");
    scanf("%d",&p[count].age);
    
}

void printMemberList(struct member p[],int count) {
    system("cls");

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        printf("\aMember %d:\n", i+1);
        printf("Name is: %s", p[i].name);
        printf("\nLast name is: %s", p[i].lastName);
        printf("\nAddress is: %s", p[i].address);
        printf("\nAge is: %d", p[i].age);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}
void saveMember(struct member p[],int count) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("member.txt","a+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File can't open.");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    fprintf(fp, MemberFormatOut, p[count].name, p[count].lastName, p[count].address, p[count].age);

    fclose(fp);
}

void fileToStructure(struct member p[],int count) {
    FILE* fp = fopen("member.txt","a+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File can't open.");
        exit(1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (int i=0; i<count+1; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, MemberFormatIn, p[i].name, p[i].lastName, p[i].address, &p[i].age);
    }
    
    

    fclose(fp);
}
int numberOfMember() {
    int count = 0;
    char c;
    FILE* fp = fopen("member.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("File can't open.");
        exit(1);
    }

    do {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if(c == '\n')
            count++;
    }while(c != EOF);

    fclose(fp);

    return count;
}
int main() {
    int len = 100;
    p1 p[len];
    int count = numberOfMember();
    inputMemberList(p,count);
    saveMember(p,count);
    fileToStructure(p,count);
    printMemberList(p,count);
    return 0;
}
```

at result just statics of member true and shown show but the others doesn't true.

File data(example):

```
(ahmad, dad, tir, 12)
(hossein, dad, tiran, 12)
(ali, dad, tir, 15)
(mohammadi, mmad, tiron, 16)
(helma, dad, tiran, 5)
(mohammad, amin, dadkhah, 5)
```

output(example):

```
Member 1:
Name is: ahmad
Last name is: dad
Address is: tir
Age is: 12

Member 2:
Name is: ├wöΩ\`
Last name is:
Address is: ↑
Age is: 0

Member 3:
Name is: Ä
Last name is: t
Address is: e
Age is: 7471221

Member 4:
Name is: r
Last name is: l
Address is: o
Age is: 6881396

Member 5:
Name is: n
Last name is: s
Address is:
Age is: 0

Member 6:
Name is:
Last name is:
Address is:
Age is: 0
```

Comment: `char c;` should be `int c;` in `numberOfMember()`.

Comment: Why is `fileToStructure()` opening the file in `a` mode if it's only reading the file?

Comment: You should always check the return value of `fscanf()` to ensure that it's successfully reading what you expect. If you did this you would see that it returns `0` except for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

In `fileToStructure()`, the first iteration of the loop calls `fscanf()` and if all is OK, the next character to be read from the file will be the newline character at the end of the first line.  Unfortunately for the next iteration, the next call to `fscanf()` is expecting to read the `(` character, but instead it reads the newline character. This will cause this call to `fscanf()` and all the subsequent calls to fail to match anything and return `EOF`.

The code needs to eat the newline character.  One way to do that is to change the `MemberFormatIn` format string to one of the following:

- `const char* MemberFormatIn=" (%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %d)";` - will discard any whitespace characters before the `(` character; or
- `const char* MemberFormatIn="(%[^,], %[^,], %[^,], %d) ";` - will discard any whitespace characters after the `)` character.

The first one (discarding whitespace before the `(` character) would be preferable for interactive input, but it doesn't matter too much when reading from a file.